# Recommended pattern for Select / Ignore / Exclude functionality

Tags: input-fields, filter, input

We have a page of filtered results, and in the sidebar the user can choose which values to filter by.

We usually use check boxes, so a user can tick an item to `select` to filter by a value or it or leave it unchecked to `ignore` it.

We need to *add* to this functionality a way to `exclude` each value.

The app must be tablet accessible so this rules out things like shift+click or right click.

How would you go about this? Primarily, we'd like to not reinvent the wheel if there is a common way to perform this action.

Things we're considering are

- radio buttons next to every value for the three options (very cluttered, even when no options are selected)
- 3-way "switch" element next to each one (not necessarily an intuitive piece of UI)

Here is the current setup (no option to exclude)

[image: Current filters]

#### Clarification on the select / ignore / exclude

Exclude is default behaviour. If I had the products:

```
red apple
green apple
```

I'd like a filter that says "Red".

If it is **un**checked, the red value is *Ignored* from the filtering logic, and the product list would still show me both products.

If I *Selected* the red value, it would show just the red apple.

If I *excluded* the red value, it would show me just the green apple.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between exclude and ignore.

Comment: @AntonMircea Hi Anton, I've added some more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You radiobuttons can be stylized to looks like tags. This approach is common for mobile apps.

[image]  [image]

Comment: Thanks Sergey, it is a good idea. My main issue is that I will have hundreds of filters, so the idea of adding sections like this is a bit daunting. Certainly an idea I will consider.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion for your filtering logic.

You have 3 options:

**Exclude item** ('excluded' checkbox selected)

**Show only item** ('show only' checkbox selected)

**Show all items** (no checkbox selected)

- 'Show only' and 'exclude' checkbox are mutually exclusive.

**You can view a working prototype here:**
https://qyt3if.axshare.com/

Hope this helps.

[image: suggestion for filter]